# Robai Cyton JointVelocity using Actins APIs

Tags: c++, qt

I'm using the `Robai Cyton Gamma 300` and trying to control the `JointVelocity`. Using the example projects provided by Robai, I created the `examplepluginGUI` and in the `AddYourCode` slot I'm trying to write a code to control the joint velocities. My current goal is to control the `JointVelocity`. Has anyone done this before? It would be great if anyone can post any example on how to do this.

I tried various methods to do that, attached is the way I'm trying to do it and the error.

```
void exampleWidget::onAddYourCode()
{
    EcRealVector JointVelocity;
    JointVelocity.push_back(0);
    JointVelocity.push_back(0.001);
    JointVelocity.push_back(1);
    JointVelocity.push_back(0.01);
    JointVelocity.push_back(0.1);
    JointVelocity.push_back(1);
    JointVelocity.push_back(0.1);
    JointVelocity.assign(JointVelocity.begin(), JointVelocity.end());

    const int* vel;
    int velo = 0.000986;
    vel = &velo;
    // ====> I dont know what data type to include in here. <====
    m_pPlugin->setParam<Ec::ParamTypeEnum::JointVelocity>(??,??,??);
    currentGuidFrameXform.setTranslation(EcVector(0.1, 0.2, 0.2));
    m_pPlugin->setParam<Ec::DesiredEndEffector>(MANIP_INDEX, 0,currentGuidFrameXform);
}
```

Here is the error I get:

> Error 1   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol
>   "__declspec(dllimport) public: bool __thiscall
>   Ec::Plugin::setParam<35,int *>(unsigned int,unsigned int,int * const
>   &)" (__imp_??$setParam@$0CD@PAH@Plugin@Ec@@QAE_NIIABQAH@Z) referenced
>   in function "protected: void __thiscall
>   exampleWidget::onAddYourCode(void)"
>   (?onAddYourCode@exampleWidget@@IAEXXZ)    C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Robai\Cyton Gamma 300R2
>   Viewer_4.0.1220160218\cyton\examples\src\cytonExampleGUIPlugin\build\exampleWidget.obj    cytonExampleGUIPlugin
>
> 3   IntelliSense: expected an expression    c:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Robai\Cyton Gamma 300R2
>   Viewer_4.0.12-20160218\cyton\examples\src\cytonExampleGUIPlugin\exampleWidget.cpp 452 56  cytonExampleGUIPlugin

Any help on this or any example codes already written to control the JointVelocity will be greatly appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

A little late for an answer, but I think you're looking for `m_pPlugin->setParam<Ec::ParamTypeEnum::JointVelocity>(MANIP_INDEX, JointVelocity);`

Not sure what version of Actin you are using, but they have some [documentation](http://outgoing.energid.info/documentation/actin_5.1.x/PAGE_PluginAPI.html) on the Plugin API on their website now.

Comment: This is an example of a great first answer. Welcome to Stack Overflow. :)